# What is the optimal index for this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following table in MYSQL 8:

```
create table session
(
    ID                           bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    session_id                   varchar(255)                                         null,
    username                     varchar(255)                                         null,
    session_status               varchar(255)                                         null,
    session_time                 int                                                  null,    
    time_created                 int                                                  null,
    time_last_updated            int                                                  null,
    time_ended                   int                                                  null,
    date_created                 date                                                 null,
);
```

I'm executing the following statement:

```
select * from session where username = VALUE and session_id = VALUE order by time_created desc
```

What is the the optimal index for the table to speed up this query?

The EXPLAIN query tells me I have two potential indexes, which are:

```
create index username_3
    on session (username, time_created);

create index username_session_id_time_created_desc
    on session (username, session_id, time_created desc);
```

I would have thought the index 'username_session_id_time_created_desc' would have been picked, however the EXPLAIN statement says that index 'username_3' is selected instead.

EDIT*

Result of SHOW CREATE TABLE session:

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_created` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_last_updated` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_ended` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `username_3` (`username`,`time_created`),
  KEY `username_session_id_time_created_desc` (`username`,`session_id`,`time_created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76149265 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Result of EXPLAIN statement:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: ref
possible_keys: username_3,username_session_id_time_created_desc
key: username_3
key_len: 768
ref: const
rows: 1
Extra: Using where
```

Comment: can you show the full output of `show create table session` and `explain select * from session where username = VALUE and session_id = VALUE order by time_created desc`?

Comment: @ysth Info added as edit.

Comment: Try the `EXPLAIN` and the query where it will be returning more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select *
from session
where username = %s and session_id = %s
order by time_created desc
```

The optimal index is `(username, session_id, time_created desc)`.  The first two columns can be in either order.

Comment: So is there a reason that the EXPLAIN statement prefers selecting the index 'username_3' over the index 'username_session_id_time_created_desc', when the second is exactly what you specified?

Comment: @vddox . . . If you have only one row, it doesn't matter.  Indexes don't become important until the tables are larger.

Comment: `rows: 1` in the `EXPLAIN` output is the key -- there's only one row that meets the `WHERE` condition, so `ORDER BY` is redundant, and it doesn't bother with that index.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought you had a typo because you wrote

```
create index username_session_id_time_created_desc on session (username, session_id, time_created desc);
```

But your create table shows

```
KEY `username_session_id_time_created_desc` (`username`,`session_id`,`time_created`)
```

instead of

```
KEY `username_session_id_time_created_desc` (`username`,`session_id`,`time_created` DESC)
```

But, I now think it is using `username_3` in MySQL 8.0 because of `backward_index_scan` [(I did not read it all)](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-descending-indexes-in-mysql/)

How you can tell : there is no `filesort` in your simple `EXPLAIN`, so it must be the optimizer can use the `username_3` index to sort your result set. (If you remove time_created from any index, you will see `Using filesort`. If you are not using MySQL 8.0, it might be that the sorting can also be done with `username_3` index in your version.)

<s>[Fiddle in 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8976d55823425702f1f0ce846c2bce6f) shows `"key": "username_session_id_time_created_desc",`</s>  : well [sometimes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0f2c32886d3985af47490dae4951834d), but not always... it might depends on the index length (field length).

[Whereas in MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e92297e862cdfc694ba4ffd4a1f13bb) it shows `"key": "username_3",` and `"backward_index_scan": true,`

[With only the 3 column index](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43fbc374932578ee093d21271e1215bd) it shows a lower query cost so why choose the other index?

My guess is that the 2 column index is much shorter, and since the backward index scan is possible, the sorting is cheap, and the optimizer still prefer to have less IO, and little more computing.